# Best approach to design 8 overloaded methods with combination of 4 parameters

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Let's assume I have a following class

```
public static class ClassA
    {
        public static Type2 B { get; set; }
        public static Type3 C { get; set; }
        public static Type4 D { get; set; }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type3 c, Type4 d)
        {
            //do smth
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type3 c)
        {
            Type4 d = D ?? defaultValue4;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type4 d)
        {
            Type3 c = C ?? defaultValue3;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type3 c, Type4 d)
        {
            Type2 b = B ?? defaultValue2;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }


        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b)
        {
            Type3 c = C ?? defaultValue3;
            Type4 d = D ?? defaultValue4;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type4 d)
        {
            Type2 b = B ?? defaultValue2;
            Type3 c = C ?? defaultValue3;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a, Type3 c)
        {
            Type2 b = B ?? defaultValue2;
            Type4 d = D ?? defaultValue4;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }

        public static string Method(Type1 a)
        {
            Type2 b = B ?? defaultValue2;
            Type3 c = C ?? defaultValue3;
            Type4 d = D ?? defaultValue4;
            return Method(a, b, c, d);
        }


}
```

In which I have to work with a combination of 4 parameters where A is always necessary and others are taken in order of priority from parameter, else from property and if no property is set or no parameter passed from its default value. 
I need to redesign this without dublicate code, so these lines

```
Type2 b = B ?? defaultValue2;
Type3 c = C ?? defaultValue3; 
Type4 d = D ?? defaultValue4;
```

a only written once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above.  Create a single method which accepts an object representing the parameters:

```
public static string Method(MethodArgs args)
{
    // ...
}
```

That `MethodArgs` can be organized however you like, either alongside this class or as an inner class perhaps or even in an entirely separate namespace of DTOs and whatnot.

Within the `MethodArgs` class you could validate the arguments, perform whatever logic you like enforcing business rules on the arguments themselves, expose functionality to manually validate that logic, etc.  Then in the `Method()` you would validate that the `args` are in some kind of valid state and proceed based on that state.

It looks like the only logic you've demonstrated here is providing default values, which could easily be encapsulated in the constructor of `MethodArgs`.

Answer (score 2):

I like David's approach because it can allow the caller more control over default values. If for some reason that's not going to work for you, I would avail myself of the optional arguments:

```
 public static string Method(Type1 a = null, Type2 b = null, Type3 c = null, Type4 d = null)
{
a = a ?? default1;
b = b ?? default2;
c = c ?? default3;
d = d ?? default4;
// logic'ing
}
```

Comment: You can combine this with David's too. Put a similar signature in the constructor of MethodArgs.

Answer (score 2):

If you need your method to accept any order of parameters, you can try this approach:

```
    public static class ClassA
{
    public static Type1 A { get; set; }
    public static Type2 B { get; set; }
    public static Type3 C { get; set; }
    public static Type4 D { get; set; }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type3 c, Type4 d)
    {
        a = a ?? default1;
        b = b ?? default2;
        c = c ?? default3;
        d = d ?? default4;
        //do smth
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type3 c)
    {
        return Method(a, b, c, D);
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b, Type4 d)
    {
        return Method(a, b, C, d);
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type3 c, Type4 d)
    {
        return Method(a, B, c, d);
    }


    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type2 b)
    {
        return Method(a, b, C, D);
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type4 d)
    {
        return Method(a, B, C, d);
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a, Type3 c)
    {
        return Method(a, B, c, D);
    }

    public static string Method(Type1 a)
    {
        return Method(a, B, C, D);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answer are wonderful but I think this approach will give you more than 8 overloaded methods but first I will use real types rather than Type1,Type2..

```
 public static string Method(int a=1, int b = 2, bool c = false, string d="")
 {
   //do something
   return "";
 }
```

in this approach you already give each parameter a default value so there is no need to check is value is passed or null so we have clean the code little bit so calling the method will be like this

```
 Method(12); // a=12,b=2,c=false,d=""
 Method(12,5); // a=12,b=5,c=false,d=""
 Method(12,5,true); // a=12,b=2,c=true,d=""
 Method(12,5,true,"Hello"); // a=12,b=2,c=true,d="Hello"
```

even more because all parameters are optional this is possible

```
 Method(); // a=1,b=2,c=false,d=""
```

and the best part is passing parameter by name

```
 Method(d:"Hello");  // a=1,b=2,c=true,d="Hello"
 Method(b:5,c:false);
 Method(d:"Hello",a:2017);
```